# How to create proper PEM file from .p12

Tags: openssl

I faced the problem of converting a PKI certificate (p12) to PEM
After converting the file to PEM, installing the certificate on the iOS device, the user cannot log in
I need a PEM certificate to transfer it to an iOS device and install it
**Base64-encoded content of the public certificate in PEM format**
https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#mobile-installcertificate
used open SSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in o-cert.p12 -nocerts -out ppkey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in o-cert.p12 -cacerts -nodes -nokeys > rootcert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in o-cert.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out servercertkey.pem
cat ppkey.pem servercert.pem rootcert.pem> server.pem
```

Comment: I checked today one thing. From my PKI certificate I got **clientcert.cer and clientcert.key**, then I created a new p12 certificate from these files and installed on iOS devices, everything works properly. I don't understand why it doesn't work when I try to install the certificate in PEM format, Because, based on the above, the PKI was correctly co-everted to .cer

Comment: On newer iOS versions, you might need to set the certificate as trusted after installing it, at Settings -> General -> About (?!) -> Certificate Trust Settings. The actual certificates should appear under Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management (or Configuration Profiles in older versions).

Comment: @telcoM I did, but it doesn't work